# TFS: Automating Task Group Creation

Tags: tfs, automation, devops

Is there a way in TFS to simplify the creation of task groups. Cloning a task group affects all environments / release definitions that reference the task group. Is there a way to automate or simplify the creation of a task group across projects?

When I say automate or simplify. I mean, how can we prevent having to recreate task groups manually across projects. Can I export the task group in TFS and automatically create a new task group in a different project with that given JSON file?

Comment: Which version of TFS are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Export/Import task group function is already available in TFS 2018 and VSTS. You could consider upgrade to TFS 2018 to enjoy this new function.

[image]

Comment: I am using TFS 2018. The import and export function is only available through the TFS GUI. I was looking for a programmatic way? like an API. I found the Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.WebApi library but it doesn't seem to be documented well so it is a bit harder to use.

Comment: @binarycoder0101 Yes, there is no document for this api available now. But you can capture the api by pressing [F12 Developer Tools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/devtools-guide/network). For example, the api of exporting task group is like: `GET http://TFSserver:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/TeamProjectID/_apis/distributedtask/taskgroups/GroupID?expanded=true&api-version=4.0-preview.1`